# Populate List box with LDAP cn and name from a specific group

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox, active-directory, listboxitems

I'm having some trouble figuring this out and this is what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to populate a list box with the "name" as the text displayed and the "cn" as the value from a specific group in Active Directory.  My code is below and it's not throwing any errors it's just not populating the list box with anything.  My guess is I'm not adding each result properly but I'm stumped.

```
Dim search As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(entry)
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf")
            search.Filter = "(memberOf=SAO Computer Grp)"
            Dim result As SearchResultCollection = search.FindAll()
            Dim ct As Integer = result.Count                
            For i = 0 To ct
                lstEmail.DataTextField = result.PropertiesLoaded("name")
                lstEmail.DataValueField = result.PropertiesLoaded("cn")
                lstEmail.DataSource = result.Item(i)
                lstEmail.DataBind()
            Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Dim search As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(entry)

search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf")

search.Filter = "(memberOf=SAO Computer Grp))"

Dim result As SearchResultCollection = search.FindAll()
Dim de As DirectoryEntry
Dim firstName, lastName As String

For Each ADUsers As SearchResult In result
    de = ADUsers.GetDirectoryEntry()
    firstName = "NA"
    lastName = "NA"

    If de.Properties("name") IsNot Nothing 
       AndAlso de.Properties("name").Count > 0 Then
            firstName = de.Properties("name")(0).ToString()
    End If

    If de.Properties("cn") IsNot Nothing 
       AndAlso de.Properties("cn").Count > 0 Then
           lastName = de.Properties("cn")(0).ToString()
    End If

    lstEmail.Items.Add(New ListItem(firstName, lastName))
Next
```

Comment: That's helping me get closer, with the search.Filter in there it's not actually returning any results so I think I need to check group memberships some other way.  Also the text it's putting into the list box with this (all users from my specific OU) isn't the name and the value field doesn't seem to be populating right.

Comment: Can you give me an example Name & CN you are expecting? Also what do you get now?

Comment: While I don't actually want the AD attributes "name" and "cn" it's the same thing.  What I want is "cn" the users actual name and "SAMAccountName" their LoginID.  What's it's filling each line in the listbox with is DC=(mydomain)

Comment: I have updated my code to use SAMAcocount, see if you can get better results

Comment: Well got it work as needed by taking out the sAMAccountName...it's not filtering by the right group in the right OU but that's something I can tweak I think.

Comment: Check my code now, the way we had search.Filter was wrong. It is now corrected!

Comment: Ok so just for reference for anyone else; @lucidgold code above works perfectly except I had to remove the search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Person))"
search.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + current_User + ")"  along with adding the full domain prefix to the AD group

Comment: Awesome, I have also updated my code to reflect your comment!